# BootMetro defining the width of the grid layout

Tags: asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap

From bootmetro:

Live grid example

The default Bootstrap grid system utilizes 12 columns, making for a 940px wide container without responsive features enabled. With the responsive CSS file added, the grid adapts to be 724px and 1170px wide depending on your viewport. Below 767px viewports, the columns become fluid and stack vertically.

I would like to have a grid that divide its 12 columns over a width of 600px, is that possible?

e.g.

```
<div class="container" width="600px">
```

That doesn't work **and** I get a warning that width is not a HTLM5 tag for divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ˋwidthˋ is just defined for tables as far as I remember. You should use the style attribute instead

```
style="width: 600px"
```

Or even better, extract the style into an external stylesheet which you incude in your HTML. For instance

```
.grid {
    width: 600px;
}
```

and then in your HTML code you add the class accordingly

```
<div class="grid"></div>
```

Makes everything much cleaner and you separate the styling from the actual HTML structure.

Comment: :) and thanks again. Can I ask you how you manage to find these questions? Are you just searching for questions with specific tags or did you find a way to get a trigger when a new question is posted?

Comment: This time it was by accident :) but I usually tag questions which could potentially interest me and based on that I'm scrolling through the stackoverflow homepage. Nothing fancy :)